# why is ECSDA signature in software protection useful? as they can be jumped over

Tags: cracking

I was reading some book and mentioned so called ECDSA ( The Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm ) is used to generate serial numbers which are difficult to crack

My understanding is that we can always STATIC/DYNAMIC analysis the assembly and change those JMP codes to what we want (CRACKing). why we spent that huge effort do that complex serial number generation ? doesn't sound worthwhile  to me.

Comment: Software developers are spending such efforts to make 'cracking' a software as big a hassle as possible. As soon as the effort overpowers the gain, people will rather resort to buying the game/software, rather than spending all the time and resources to crack it. And that's the point. Because, after all, it's next to impossible to keep track of 'where' your software is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there are techniques that enforces the EXECUTABLE file sanity checks, this technique together with the binary code protection techniques drive the software protection vehicle running forward